# Solc "bin-runtime" not a command?

Tags: solc

I can generate the .bin of a contract with solc as follows:

```
solcjs --bin -o output contract.sol
```

However running the following command:

```
solcjs --bin-runtime -o output contract.sol
```

Generates the following:

> Invalid option selected, must specify either --bin or --abi

Is `bin-runtime` still a valid command in solc?

Comment: Did you get it sorted? [This](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13086/solc-bin-vs-bin-runtime/13087#13087) may help.

Answer (score 0):

`bin-runtime` is an option for solc, but you're using solcjs. [Here are instructions for installing solc.](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html#building-from-source)