# How to verify if an address is an instance of the desired smart contract?

Tags: web3js, addresses

Given an address (in server-side javascript), is there a way to check that the address is an instance of a specific smart contract?

I've tried using

```
web3.eth.getCode(addr)
```

for a recently deployed contract, but this gives me slightly different bytecode (ie same prefix and postfix with some similar stuff in between) than what was used to deploy it. Am I missing something, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: But presumably if you deploy the contract again and call `getCode` on _that_ address, you get the same bytecode as the first deployment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you solidity compiler solc to return the bytecode that will be placed on an address, you need to compile using the argument `--bin-runtime` instead of `--bin`.

So to check that the code placed on an address represents the source code in question, you need to compare what is returned by `web3.eth.getCode(addr)` with the output of `solc -o outputDirectory --bin-runtime sourceFile.sol`.

The reason for this is that `--bin-runtime` will contain the bytecode that is placed on the blockchain whereas `--bin` will contain the bytecode that is placed on the blockchain **plus** the code that is needed to actually place the code on the blockchain, i.e. the constructor. For an in-depth explanation, have a look at: [solc bin vs. bin-runtime](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13086/solc-bin-vs-bin-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a factory to deploy instances of the contract, then the factory can be an authoritative registry and remove all doubt.

Hope it helps.