# What is the "clone-bin" output in solc?

Tags: solc, bytecode

When it comes to bytecode `solc` has three types of outputs:

```
--bin                Binary of the contracts in hex.
--bin-runtime        Binary of the runtime part of the contracts in hex.
--clone-bin          Binary of the clone contracts in hex.
```

The first two are clear and were explained in detail [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13086/solc-bin-vs-bin-runtime?rq=1), but I can't find anything about `clone-bin`. What is it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think** it's the same as --bin but for a cloned contract. 
a cloned contract is a clone created based on another contract's bytecode.
checkout this clone factory : https://github.com/optionality/clone-factory to get an idea.