# Encode constructor arguments used when deploying a contract

Tags: web3js, abi, bytecode, constructor

How can I encode the constructor arguments when deploying a contract?

Here is my deployment function:

```
async function deploy(abi, bin, args) {
    let contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
    let transaction = contract.deploy({data: "0x" + bin, arguments: args});
    let handle = await this.send(transaction);
    return new this.web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), handle.contractAddress);
}
```

Inside this function, I can do the following:

1. `console.log(transaction.arguments);`
2. `console.log(transaction.encodeABI());`

The 1st option just prints the values of the arguments as is.

The second option prints the entire byte-code.

My encoded arguments indeed appear at the end of this byte-code.

But since I don't know the length of this suffix, I cannot easily "cut it" out of the byte-code.

One option I have in mind, is that the length of this suffix is `64 * args.length`, since every argument is padded to 256-bits (64 hexadecimal digits).

But I don't think that this will work when some of the arguments are strings or arrays.

Is there any standard solution for this in web3.js?

Thank you!

Comment: Some additional observations: an array yields one additional "argument" which denotes the array-length (padded to 256 bits). This argument precedes the actual values in the array (each of which, also padded to 256 bits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OK, found a way to do this:**

If the value of `bin` starts with `0x`:

```
let encodedArgs = transaction.encodeABI().slice(bin.length)
```

If the value of `bin` does not start with `0x`:

```
let encodedArgs = transaction.encodeABI().slice(2 + bin.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a standard solution, but the Solidity compiler can give you the binary data that will be placed on the blockchain through the [bin-runtime](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13086/solc-bin-vs-bin-runtime) command. This will be like the `bin` but without the constructor (the first part of the `bin` output) and the constructor arguments (the last part of the `bin` output). So you should be able to look at the end of `bin-runtime` and find where this occurs in the `bin` output. The first byte after this place should be the start of the ABI encoding of the constructor arguments.

Comment: I already wrote this in my question (quoting): `My encoded arguments indeed appear at the end of this byte-code.

But since I don't know the length of this suffix, I cannot easily "cut it" out of the byte-code.`. So unless I'm missing something, I don't see how this answer adds anything to what I already know. I am looking for an **automated way** for extracting the constructor arguments encoded string from the deployed byte-code.

Comment: My answer gives you a way of finding the length of the suffix.

Comment: So I need to look into the network (via etherscan or similar)? I already know how to do this, but it is not an automated way for achieving my purpose (and it is not via web3.js either).

Comment: Do you have the source code of the contract you are deploying? I don't think you should have to look at the blockchain. You need to call the solidity compiler with the "bin-runtime" argument and compare that with the "bin" output. `solc --bin-runtime file.sol`

Comment: Oh, OK. In the answer that you've liked, I see `eth.getCode(contractaddress)` at the bottom. I will give it a try and update you. Thank you!

Comment: Well, it doesn't help, but I've just realized that I can simply compare between `bin` and `transaction.encodeABI()`, and the data that I need should be exactly the difference (i.e., the suffix added in the latter).